# Inverse function of bi- or tri-exponential decay

Tags: exponential-function, inverse-function

This is my first post ever on this forum. I am a medical doctor working within the field of clinical pharmacology, and not a mathematician.

Bi- or triexponential decay functions are often used to model how drug concentrations change with time. In pharmacology, the bi-exponential decay function is typically formualted as follows:

$C(t)=A\cdot e^{-k_1\cdot t}+B\cdot e^{-k_2\cdot t}$

And the tri-exponential decay function:

$C(t)=A\cdot e^{-k_1\cdot t}+B\cdot e^{-k_2\cdot t}+D\cdot e^{-k_3\cdot t}$

$t$ is the time in hours. $C(t)$ is the drug concentration at time $t$. $k_1$, $k_2$ and $k_3$ are rate constants. $A$, $B$ and $D$ are coefficients whose sum is the initial drug concentration at time zero. All parameters are positive, real numbers.

I am working on a digital tool that requires the following question to be answered: how many hours must pass until the drug concentration is $x$ (where $x$ is some arbitrary number)?

Is it possible to find the inverse function of the bi- and tri-exponential functions above? If not, is there any other way for to easily solve the problem without using graphical or iterative methods?

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do not hesitate to ask if anything is not clear. The problem is quite simple (numerically).

Comment: For one given drug, are the parameters fixed (at least for a long time period) ? If this is true, we could associate to each drug a specific approximation better than what I did propose. Please, let me know. Cheers :-)

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up. For the purposes of the current project, I am assuming that the parameters are fixed. It would seem that the sum of two exponential functions fits the data well. (The question of a tri-exponential function was mostly out of curiosity, and because it may prove useful in other projects in the future.)

Comment: Have a look at my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the most general case, you cannot inverse the sum of exponential functions and you need some numerical method (Newton being the simplest.

But, instead of trying to solve for $t$
$$C(t)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\, e^{-k_i t}$$ solving
$$\log[C(t)]=\log\Big[\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\, e^{-k_i t}\Big]$$ would be much better since the rhs is much closer to linearity.

So, let us say that we look for the zeo of function
$$f(t)=\log\Big[\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\, e^{-k_i t}\Big]-k$$ $k$ being given.

We have
$$f(0)=\log\Big[\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\Big]-k >0\qquad \text{and}\qquad  f''(0) >0$$ So, by Darboux theorem, starting iterations at $t_0=0$ ensures that we shall never face an overshoot of the solution.

But we can try to make an estimate trying to write
$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\, e^{-k_i t}\sim A\,e^{-K t}=C(0)\,e^{-K t}$$ and define
$$\frac {\sum_{i=1}^n a_i }K=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac {a_i}{k_i}\implies K=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i  } {\sum_{i=1}^n \frac {a_i}{k_i} }$$ to match the areas under the curves from $t=0$ to $\infty$.

Trying withe random numbers
$$a_1=29.8488\qquad a_2=50.0334\qquad a_3=21.9958$$
$$k_1=0.109865\qquad k_2=0.0760897\qquad k_3=0.0650516$$ gives $A=101.878 $ and $K=0.0803852$.

By curiosity, plot the two curves (they almost overlap).

Suppose that the target is $C(t)=45.678$; this gives as an estimate $t=9.97895$.

Now, Newton iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
m & t_m \\
 0 & 9.97895 \\
 1 & 9.76084 \\
 2 & 9.76091
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit** *(for the biexponential decay function)*

Since it is better to work on a logarithmic scale, consider that we want to approximate

$$\log\Big[ a_1\, e^{-k_1 t}+ a_2\, e^{-k_2 t}\Big]\qquad \text{by} \qquad \log\big[ a_1+ a_2\big]- K t$$ and consider two points $t_i=\frac{\log(2)}{k_i}$ corresponding to the half-times.

Minimzing the sum of the squared errors leads to
$$(t_1^2+t_2^2) K=(t_1+t_2) \log(a_1+a_2)-$$ $$\Big[t_1 \log \left(a_1 e^{-k_1 t_1}+a_2 e^{-k_2 t_1}\right)+t_2
   \log \left(a_1 e^{-k_1 t_2}+a_2 e^{-k_2 t_2}\right)\Big]$$

Trying with $a_1=30$, $k_1=0.11$, $a_2=50$, $k_2=0.07$, this would give $K\sim 0.0834$. Trying for a few values of $C(t)$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 C(t) & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 70 & 1.60118 &  1.57641 \\
 60 & 3.44960 &  3.40984 \\
 50 & 5.63582 &  5.59716 \\
 40 & 8.31154 &  8.30198 \\
 30 & 11.7611 &  11.8338 \\
 20 & 16.6231 &  16.8954 \\
 10 & 24.9346 &  25.7633
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using this estimate, Newton method would converge very fast. For example, using the last (and worst) point, we would have
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & t_n \\
 0 & 24.9346 \\
 1 & 25.7623 \\
 2 & 25.7633
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much for a very clear and useful answer!